# Angular UI not rendering after published in Service Fabric (working fine in local)

Tags: angular, azure-service-fabric

Angular UI not rendering after publishing in Service Fabric. But when published in local, UI seems fine.

Earlier I saw few errors in the UI console. So I reinstalled few packages and now I cant see any errors in the UI console. I have retried many things like changing Visual studio version, updating packages, etc. But not sure what I am missing.

**Note**: Updated the compatible service fabric packages too.

Can some one let me know if I am missing something?

**Edge:**

[image: Angular Edge]

**Chrome**

[image: Angular chrome]

Answer (score 0):

This happens in IE because by default polyfills are commented for IE in  `polyfills.ts`  file. Still you can check for other browsers as well.

Please check  [browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) here for angular.